# How do you resolve "nearest" when it is tied in Betrayal at House on the Hill?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

If a game effect is supposed to happen to something which is nearest to something else, and more than one qualifying thing is equally near, and the specific effect does not designate a tie-breaker, how is the tie resolved?  Is it the choice of the person resolving the effect?  Or, if it is possible (as in the case of the card that prompted this question, Footsteps, which has as it's best result "You and the nearest explorer gain 1 Might.") does it happen to all potential targets?

(In the game I was playing where it came up, there were two explorers who were each 3 rooms away from the explorer who drew the card.  The question then became, does the explorer who drew the card choose one of them or did it happen to both of them.  No support for either case could be found in rulebook, FAQ, or this site.  So the question has now been posed here.)

I would prefer a general answer, rather than one more specifically about Footsteps, as knowing the appropriate way to resolve the general situation is far more important than any specific ruling about the individual card.  However, if there **is** any sort of official rulling/clarification/errata/etc. about this aspect of Footsteps that my web search failed to uncover, feel free to site it, as it would have bearing on the more general situation of which it is an example.

Comment: Could you add in which specific card was pulled?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee  It was actually already mentioned twice in the question: The card was Footsteps.  However, as I said, I'm far more interested in the general principal than the specific instance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an official ruling on how to break that tie, but I would go with the official way to break ties for traitor, when the traitor is the one with the highest/lowest stat, and that is to use the closest player involved in the tie to the left of the player that triggered the haunt. So you would in this case break the tie by hitting the closest player who's explorer is involved in the tie going around the table to your left.

I don't have the rules on hand right now so I can't quote the book for that. Note this is the method for the original betrayal and I believe Betrayal at Baulders Gate. Betrayal Legacy uses a different mechanic to break ties, randomly drawing from the family crests of those players involved in the tie.